# How to disconnect specific ssh client from ssh server in linux?

Tags: server, ssh, 20.04, client

I wonder if i can disconnect a specific ssh client from ssh server?

Can we do that?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/615/how-do-you-kick-a-benign-user-off-your-system

Comment: i already killed the client, but in client, it still connected to the server...

Comment: That exact case is addressed in the Stackexchange thread.

Answer (score 2):

This is answered here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/615/how-do-you-kick-a-benign-user-off-your-system/622#622

A copy of the steps:

There's probably an easier way, but I do this:

1. See who's logged into your machine -- use `who` or `w`:

   ```
    > who  
    mmrozek  tty1         Aug 17 10:03  
    mmrozek  pts/3        Aug 17 10:09 (:pts/2:S.0)
   ```
2. Look up the process ID of the shell their TTY is connected to:

   ```
    > ps t  
    PID   TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND  
    30737 pts/3    Ss     0:00 zsh
   ```
3. Laugh at their impending disconnection (this step is optional, but encouraged)

   ```
    > echo "HAHAHAHAHAHAHAHA" | write mmrozek pts/3
   ```
4. Kill the corresponding process:

   ```
    > kill -9 30737
   ```

---

I just discovered you can combine steps 1 and 2 by giving `who` the `-u` flag; the PID is the number off to the right:

```
> who -u
mmrozek  tty1         Aug 17 10:03 09:01        9250
mmrozek  pts/18       Aug 17 10:09 01:46       19467 (:pts/2:S.0)
```